# How to convert keras CuDNNLSTM layer to LSTM (and CuDNNGRU to GRU)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am trying to convert `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` to `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` (and `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU` to `tf.keras.layers.GRU`).

I see from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003418/using-keras-how-can-i-load-weights-generated-from-cudnnlstm-into-lstm-model) and [this GitHub PR](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/8307) that the CuDNNLSTM --> LSTM conversion is possible, and I see from [this GitHub PR](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9112) that the conversion is possible, but I'm seeing some unexpected behavior during inference, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

The way I am doing this now is through creating (and training) a model which has a `CuDNNLSTM` layer...

```
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(120,))
    x = layers.CuDNNLSTM(100)(inputs)   # or x = layers.CuDNNGRU(100)(inputs)
    outputs = layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

... compiling and training the model ...

```
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(...)
```

... saving the model as both a json for the structure and an hdf5 file for weights, and editing the file to say it's an `LSTM` layer instead of a `CuDNNLSTM` layer.

```
    model.save_weights('/path/to/weights.h5')
    # get json, edit layer name, dump into file
    json_config = model.to_json()
    with open('/path/to/structure.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_config_ = json.loads(json_config)
        layers = json_config_['config']['layers']
        for layer in layers:
            if layer['class_name'].lower() == 'cudnnlstm':
                layer['class_name'] = 'LSTM'
            elif layer['class_name'].lower() == 'cudnngru':
                layer['class_name'] = 'GRU'

        json.dump(json_config_, json_file)
```

I am taking `'/path/to/weights.h5'` and `'/path/to/structure.json'` and converting them to coreml to do inference on an iphone, so it might be failing during the coreml conversion. I want to check if I am doing the conversion from CuDNN layers to LSTM/GRU layers correctly first, before investigating the coreml converter. **Is this the correct way to convert from CuDNNLSTM to LSTM and from CuDNNGRU to GRU? Is there another way to do the conversion that I should be doing instead?**

Comment: Have you tried running the resulting LSTM model?

Comment: Do you mean run the LSTM not in coreml, just running in Keras?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: No, good point, I'll try that.